# Error Android App Bundle no válido

Tags: android, google-play, apk, firma-digital

Buenos días acabo de firmar una apk y la estoy intentando subir a Google play.
Al subirla a https://apkpure.com/es/apk-signature-verification me muestra que está bien firmada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al intentar subirla a Google Play como una nueva versión de una app existente me muestra el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema aquí es que tu .APK en realidad esta firmado pero en este caso probablemente esta usando información de otro certificado, probablemente uno antiguo, por esta razón no te permite subir el .apk a Google Play Store.

Vuelve a construir tu proyecto, mediante `Clean Project`, firma nuevamente el .APK y cárgalo nuevamente.

Si es una actualización y usas un .jks, asegura seleccionar el correcto certificado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]